# how to load a div content in another div using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, forms, master-pages

I have one web content form referenced by master page. i need to load the content of div into another div. I am unable to call the content as jquery throws error. Any help will be truely appreciated.

Thanks in advance
S S HUSSAIN

Comment: Can't see your code, don't know what your error is, no way to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these

```
//Copies the inner HTML of source
$("#id_of_target_div").html($("#id_of_source_div").html());

//moves the source div into target
$("#id_of_target_div").append($("#id_of_source_div"));

//Moves children of source into target
$("#id_of_target_div").append($("#id_of_source_div").children());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following.

```
// you can copy the html and put it in the target div.
$('#target_div').html($('#source_div').html());

// You can clone the div and put it in target.
$('#source_div').clone().appendTo($('#target_div'));
```